# Pass an object in v-model with VuejS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity, vue-multiselect

I'm having trouble with v-model in vue multiselect.  Multiselect requires an object to be passed into v-model to have an initial selected value so it can match that object with the options Object.
Here is a sample of my code:

```
<b-tr v-for="(income, index) in this.incomes" :key="income.id">
     <b-td>
          <multiselect
            :options="selectAccount"
            v-model="{id:income.account_id,account:income.accounts.account}"
            label="account"
            track-by="id"
          ></multiselect>
        </b-td>
</b-tr>
```

Vue does not accept passing an Object into v-model this way and I can't figure out another way to do this.

Here is the incomes Object:

```
incomes: Array
  0: Object
    account_id:
    accounts: Object
      account: 
      id:
    amount:
    id:
    date:
```

Options:

```
options: Array[3]
  0: Object
    account:
    id:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make v-model related to an array that you pass each element by index of main array like:

```
v-model="selected_options[index]"
```

and set selected_value as an array:

```
selected_options: []
```

Comment: Thank You very much. This solved my problem. I dont get it why your answer is not accepted here.

Answer (score 0):

Can't use `v-model` with multiple values:

> "Component v-model is designed for single value input components that
>   attend to similar use cases for native input elements.
>
> For a complex component that manages the synchronization of more than
>   one values, explicit prop/event pairs is the proper solution. In this
>   particular case I don't think the saved keystrokes are worth the added
>   complexity of additional syntax."
>
> - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4946

PS. Support for multiple values with `v-model` is coming in Vue v3 at the end of Q1/20, with syntax like `v-model:id="income.account_id"`

Comment: Multiselect accepts a value for v-model which references an object in the data class (sorry if I'm using the wrong terms). https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-select-with-search.

Comment: @paulB try this: `<multiselect v-model="income" track-by="account_id" label="accounts.account"></multiselect>`